# How to See InputData of Transaction without ABI?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, rinkeby

I have a contract (0x4ab57f1bfacfa668640ee7f464ae73af28810fb3 https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x4ab57f1bfacfa668640ee7f464ae73af28810fb3) in RinkeBy, with that source:
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

```
contract TRRT {
    string private a="AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDyAAB/ABtTlMBttlaKKQhjay2Cs5y79qWHpaJNYzS6oVQTN134a2JexiG5CumdETASFrQ8gZAeHxNyKz1qcLOxjonS5PJIBDpTkxE3yQm0gu9TBMFdA7Ni48l2QG1B5tO3D8mpxBWNDNXUE9ZpLzW3albmnW5+R4euWpsfpL1mRwNtrLJqGrE7vdGM8G79AscVjMkjHOfJV7AEp0rZ6Aq6vilY0lVLW+dJfbU5DNKvIM9s32nax8iDJBx3ld3YUsBJX7VL2T2xcp3DmrdctF3jYXvcYbyrwPFv1LJ3lf71Jx32Z+xprgkIliaORfZv48rXR/k2BfJJ6+f4Iim3L9X1";
    function ShowKey()public constant returns (string) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

How can i get Input Data, result of my function, without ABI, from another account?(I know, that i can copy it ath the rinkeby.etherscan.io, but i want to get it with geth/web3 or similar way.

Actually, i too don't need smart contract, i need just to publish data, that is contained in "a", mb you will help me to avoid excess hemorrhoids.

Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear on why you say "without ABI?" The ABI is what describes what functions are available on your smart contract.

If you're okay using a minimal ABI, this successfully retrieves the string from your smart contract:

```
web3.eth.contract([{constant:true,inputs:[],name:"ShowKey",outputs:[{type:"string"}],type:"function"}])
.at("0x4ab57f1bfacfa668640ee7f464ae73af28810fb3")
.ShowKey((err, result) => {console.log(result);});
```

That said, I'm not entirely sure what the purpose here is, so maybe I misunderstood your question. If this didn't help, please do clarify the question.

Comment: Hello!Did i understand right, that request u gave will show me string from "a"? If it is - this will be resolution. I didn't want to use ABI, cause default one from Mist already contains my "a" string :D I will try to do, like you said and write here.

Comment: Yes, that line of code should output the string `"AAAAB3..."`.

Comment: Thx, it worked for me :)